# How to make Chrome extension save to specific location instead of open "save as" window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i im trying to edit a google chrome extension that converts youtube urls to mp3 files. Currently it asks for a save location every time i download a video and i would like to set it up so that it automatically downloads to my music folder without any popup.

Im just fiddling with settings in background.js specifically chrome.downloads.download but really have no idea what im doing.

For you experienced programmers i think it will be like grade 1 knowledge so i would appreciate the help :D

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#property-options-filename

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that from javascript you have to set det download folder in the browser. However if you set the folder you can set the flag SaveAs to false so that the file always will end up in your download folder.

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url:      url,
    filename: fileName,
    saveAs:   false
});
```